# R import excel file following some pattern

Tags: r, date, wildcard

I am trying to import a excel file from local. assume the now is Jun 2018, the file name is like this:

```
20180620 data 201803.xlsx
```

so you can see first part is the date they create the file, and the file is for the data of `201803`, which is at the end of file name.

and sometimes there are multiple files in Jun 2018 created for 201803, and I always want the latest file. e.g. `20180620 data 201803.xlsx` vs `20180614 data 201803.xlsx`,I want `20180620 data 201803.xlsx`

currently this is my code, but I dont know how to always pick the latest date file. Any idea how to do that? Thank you!

```
list = list.files(path = folder, pattern = paste0(substr(today,1,4),substr(today,6,7),".xlsx$"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have something that does just that. Here's the solution I'm using:

```
files<-list.files(pattern=".xlsx")
file<-files[file.info(files)$ctime==max(file.info(files)$ctime)]
data<-readxl::read_excel(file)
```

This assumes that the files in the directory will only be in the format you suggested. Otherwise you might want to put in some pattern.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your post. I can find the latest file now~~